# Прочесть CSV (число столбцов может меняться) с вложенными JSON строками в плоскую структуру, правильно распознав типы данных

Tags: python, csv

Обрабатываю записи из csv–файла:

```
with open(self.prefix + filename, 'rt', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        id, body, link, score, parent_id, creation_date, author_id = row
        ...
```

Пришла новая форма cvs–файла, где под 20 колонок. Двадцать переменных в строку выглядят очень пугающе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом обработать такой случай в python–стиле (меньше года, понятнее, проще)?

**Обновление**

После того, как я разобрал файл, я, при необходимости, привожу переменные к python–типам (целые числа, даты и тд), затем небольшая логика и сохраняю в базу данных (с SQLAlchemy).

**Обновление 2**

Пример данных входного файла. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что некоторые файлы могут содержать «заголовок», а некоторые — нет (какие файлы содержат/не содержат заголовок я знаю).

```
CommentId,Text,Post Link,PostScore,ParentPostId,CommentCreationDate,CommentAuthorId,CommentAuthorUsername,PostAuthorId,DiffOfPost
"1244716","тут идет какой–то текст","{
  ""id"": 790386,
  ""title"": ""тут идет какой–то текст""
}","0","","2018-02-26 08:57:37","185343","Автор","233080","1694"
"1244061","тут идет какой–то текст","{
  ""id"": 790064,
  ""title"": ""тут идет какой–то текст""
}","1","","2018-02-25 13:56:41","194908","Автор","274105","1461"
```

Comment: а что вы хотите с этим CSV делать? Вариант использования Pandas рассматривали?

Comment: @MaxU Обновил вопрос. Подскажите, как я могу облегчить свою судьбу с Pandas в данном случае?

Comment: Какая у вас СУБД?

Comment: PostgreSQL. Приложение использует Flask и SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** пример с использованием приведенных в вопросе данных:

```
import json

In [171]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\1.csv', parse_dates=['CommentCreationDate'])
     ...:
     ...: df = df.join(df.pop('Post Link').apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series))
     ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [172]: df
Out[172]:
   CommentId                     Text  PostScore  ParentPostId CommentCreationDate  CommentAuthorId CommentAuthorUsername  \
0    1244716  тут идет какой–то текст          0           NaN 2018-02-26 08:57:37           185343                 Автор
1    1244061  тут идет какой–то текст          1           NaN 2018-02-25 13:56:41           194908                 Автор

   PostAuthorId  DiffOfPost      id                    title
0        233080        1694  790386  тут идет какой–то текст
1        274105        1461  790064  тут идет какой–то текст
```

Типы данных столбцов DataFrame'а:

```
In [173]: df.dtypes
Out[173]:
CommentId                         int64
Text                             object
PostScore                         int64
ParentPostId                    float64
CommentCreationDate      datetime64[ns]
CommentAuthorId                   int64
CommentAuthorUsername            object
PostAuthorId                      int64
DiffOfPost                        int64
id                                int64
title                            object
dtype: object
```

PS если файл не содержит заголовок (имен столбцов), но они вам известны, то можно сделать так:

```
cols = ['col1_name', 'col2_name', ..., 'colN_name']
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['CommentCreationDate'], header=None, names=cols)
```

---

**первоначальный ответ**

С использованием Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

conn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.to_sql('table_name', conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

PS [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) автоматически распознает практически все типы данных (кроме даты/времени)

Чтобы преобразовать столбец типа `datetime`:

```
df['date_col_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col_name'])
```

---

Можно также воспольоваться [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in csv_reader:
    # теперь можно обращаться к значениям по именам столбцов:
    # row['id']
    # row['body']
```

PS вариант с использованием Pandas, по-моему, гораздо короче, код легче читается и поддерживается и работает обычно гораздо быстрее...

Comment: т.е. вам надо превратить этот JSON в плоскую структуру - я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Да, верно.  Я разбираю это так `data = json.loads(post_link)` и далее обращаюсь к `data` как к словарю.